# Access inner function variable outside JavaScript function

Tags: javascript

I needs to access the variable outside the function,

**Example:**

```
var testData = "LoadedVariable";
    function loadFunction(){
        testData = "DynamicVariable";
    }
    alert(testData);

<div onclick="loadFunction();" style="cursor: pointer;">
turn around click
</div>
```

As per above example, on page load i can access testData as "LoadedVariable". But, when i clicks the button, testData needs to change to "DynamicVariable".

This is for dynamic chat functionality for single web app application.

How to trigger the alert when i clicks button. I know we can alert it inside the function. But i need to achieve the result in above example format.

Thanks in advance.

I added the same in [**JSFIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/mrvijayakumar/yw6pf87s/)

Comment: Not quite sure what you are asking.  Here's a post on variable scope in javascript: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500431/what-is-the-scope-of-variables-in-javascript  If you still need information and can better describe what you are trying to accomplish it will be easier for someone to provide a solution

Comment: do you want to observe the variable for change and alert accordingly?

Comment: i am not sure how what you want is different from a normal ```callback```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem isn't one of variable scoping. In fact, if you test your example code:

```
var testData = "LoadedVariable";
function loadFunction(){
    testData = "DynamicVariable";
}
alert(testData);
```

you'll see it actually works correctly: it alerts "LoadedVariable".

Your problem is actually a timing one:

```
<div onclick="loadFunction();" style="cursor: pointer;">
```

What that is saying is, "run a function which changes my variable" ... but not "run a function which changes my variable AND alerts it". You only have one `alert`, which occurs when the page loads, so when your `div` gets clicked and you call `loadFunction` nothing happens. Behind the scenes your `testData` variable has become "DynamicVariable", you just can't tell without an `alert`.

As others have suggested, you could solve this timing problem by moving the alert inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

**Working Example**

http://jsfiddle.net/yw6pf87s/1/

```
function loadFunction() {
  testData = "DynamicVariable";
  return testData;
}

alert(loadFunction());
```

**My Reccommendation**

```
function loadFunction(newValue){
  testData = newValue;
  alert(testData);
}
```

HTML

```
<div onclick="loadFunction('New Value');" style="cursor: pointer;">turn around click</div>
```

Comment: I don't recommend it but it's a direct answer to the question ;(

Answer (score 0):

Just use a separate function as click handler. Have the click handler call `loadFunction` and then `alert`:

```
<div id="turnaround" style="cursor: pointer;">
turn around click
</div>

<script>
var testData = "LoadedVariable",
    loadFunction = function () {
        testData = "DynamicVariable";
    },
    clickHandler = function () {
      loadFunction();
      alert(testData);
    },
    turnaround = document.getElementById('turnaround');

turnaround.addEventListener('click', clickHandler, false);
</script>
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/UselessCode/d3agfw8L/1/)